# which is the best way to validate an input with jQuery? onChange / onKeyUp. Or what other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, onkeyup

someone could explain which of the two is the best and why? or if there is a better option.

also is there other options like keydown, blur, change...

"why" is very  importan. thanks a lot.

Comment: `onchange` *because my task tells me to*. (Read: Depends on what's needed, not because of what is "best"). Also, "best" doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for your 3 replies, all complement each other and see different points. 
and showed me things I had not considered.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer , what you say is true but I needed to get these views, as you can see are very good. Or "best" could exist when need to choose a way. thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onKeyUp` would result in the validation routines running after every key press. This could be viable if using a `setTimeout` as mentioned by @APAD1, but depending on the time, the user could leave the field before the validation routine, and depending on the form have submitted before the validation routine. This can also be very heavy. I would generally only use `onKeyUp` if you can validate the individual key press and swallow it. If you are waiting for final input to validate, then use `onChange` or `onBlur`.

`onChange` works for any field that would be picked up by the $(":input") selector (e.g. radios, selects, SLEs, etc). This is useful if you want to validate when they leave, but will only work if you re-focus the field and clear the bad contents. Else they could just ignore the error and keep going. If they never re-change the contents, the validation won't fire.

`onBlur` is very good if you want to validate as soon as input is complete and the field loses focus. I caution using this, depending on how you are notifying the user of the error. If you are alerting or doing something like re-focusing the field, then you can create a bad, blocking user experience.

As a general thought process, it is good to do instant validation on inputs, but inform the user in a non-blocking way (e.g. pop a div next to the field or something). ALWAYS preform a final validation of the entire form before sending information, as in some cases it could be possible for the user to ignore the validation messages, and subsequently send bad information.

Comment: +1 for explaining the various methods and the caveat of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, onKeyUp is the better solution depending on the project. This is because you can give the user semi-instant indication of whether their input is valid or not(adding a green checkmark or a red "X" next to the input once they've finished typing), whereas, with onChange/blur, they do not see the validation until they tab out of the input.

However, you obviously don't want it to validate immmediately on keyUp either, because it would be annoying, so I've found that the best way to address this is to use keyUp with a timer so that it doesn't validate until 1-2 seconds after they've stopped typing.

You can do that like this:

```
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //Validation delay time in ms

$('input').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(validationFunction, doneTypingInterval); //replace validationFunction with the name of your function
});
```

Comment: But by the time that 1-2 second time is over, they could've easily tabbed onto the next input ---

Comment: The input would still validate.

Comment: Absolutely, and I'm not saying there's anything wrong with doing it this way, but in that case, you may as well use .blur() --- 

Or perhaps make the timer <1s

Comment: I've found that users who tab through forms will usually tab through all the inputs, but then use their mouse or hit "enter" to submit, so if you use onChange/blur, they'll get to the end of the form and their cursor will remain in the last input and the validation never gets fired.

Comment: I typically just force a blur event on all form elements onSubmit -

Comment: But then the validation doesn't take place until they submit. Based on the way the OP posed the question, it seems like they're looking for the validation to take place prior to the form being submitted.

Comment: @APAD1 On the contrary, if he is forcing a blur of each field in the submit, then he obviously has validation routines defines for the blur event of those fields. So he would indeed get both instant and final validation.

Comment: I think add time to KEYUP opens the door to more errors, but it is a VERY good idea for other applications. tanks APAD1 and @rm-vanda

Answer (score 1):

onChange only works on certain types of elements (`<SELECT>` for e.g.).

onKeyUp will evaluate with every keypress, which is "heavy"

`blur()` is perhaps better because it is triggered each time you leave a field. But what about when you are still in the field and click the submit button?

Therefore, onsubmit is the best solution -- or a combination of the two. There is no problem with evaluating different ways for different fields, and validating again after clicking submit

Comment: Clicking submit would cause focus to be drawn to the button, thus blurring the input.

Comment: thanks for this important detail, validate before sending. really good.